# FiIeInfo.CreationTime. How to read correct value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asyncfileupload, fileinfo

I have file upload control on .aspx page, I want to upload an image at a time whose location is not always the same, could be in same directory as .sln, on desktop, anywhere.

I am using this code to read the file creation time

```
string savePath = MapPath("~/" + Path.GetFileName(e.FileName));
FileInfo MyFileInfo = new FileInfo(savePath);

string dt = MyFileInfo.CreationTime.Day.ToString();
string mn = MyFileInfo.CreationTime.Month.ToString();
string yr = MyFileInfo.CreationTime.Year.ToString();
```

I have noticed one thing that

If the image is in the same folder as the website, it gives me correct values for all

`dt` , `mn` and  `yr`

But if it's outside that location, it always gives me same value everytime

> {01/01/1601 00:00:00}

Not sure how to sort this out?
any advice, helpful code? thanks

Comment: I suspect you've just got the wrong filename - or you don't have permission to read the file. From the docs: "If the file described in the FileSystemInfo object does not exist, this property will return 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time."

Comment: I see, I have MyFileInfo.Exists = false, so this makes sense when I am trying to access a file thats in different directory, But I was wondering if there isany other way around to this?

Comment: Well we'd have to know exactly what's wrong first. It may well just be a permissions issue - have you given permission for the appropriate ASP.NET account to see that file?

Comment: That is new to me. How can i do that? Thanks

Comment: How do you pass the different directory name? The `~/` before the e.FileName refers to the root of your site. So you need a relative path to reach a directory outside your site root

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

It seems you do not understand the client/server barrier yet. Paths from the client are not meaningful on the server.

It so happens that your website is running on the same machine as the client because you are debugging locally. That is just a coincidence and it allows your code to sometimes work (by coincidence).

Proper file uploading works by ignoring the path and reading from the stream provided by the file upload control. A file upload is just a stream of bytes to the server.